# What happens with shared edges when taking the (non disjoint) union of graphs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

The union of two graphs $G = (V_0, E_0, \phi_0)$ and $H = (V_1, E_1, \phi_1)$ is defined to be a graph $K$, with $V(K) = V_0 \cup V_1$ and $ E(K) = E_0 \cup E_1$.

I think there is no problem if the vertex sets $V_j$ and the edge sets, $E_j$ are disjoint. If the vertex sets share some elements then we may run into a situation where the resulting graph is a multigraph, which is a bit annoying but I can accept it. But if the edge sets share an element, say, $E_0 \cap E_1 = \{e\}$ then there will be an issue if $e$ is incident to different vertices in $H$ and $G$. The incidence function for $K$
$ \phi: E_0 \cup E_1 \to \{\{v, w\} : v, w \in V_0 \cup V_1, v \ne w\}$ will not be right-unique if we try to extend it the naive way, since there is no value we can assign to $\phi(e)$.

I wonder what is the usual way in which people solve this issue, it seems to me that probably the most natural thing is to artificially distinguish the elements of both edge sets to always make them disjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an awkward hole in the definition that virtually never comes up in problems which we want to phrase in terms of unions of graphs. (If it did come up, I imagine that we would want to make the edge sets artificially disjoint.)

In practice, when taking the union of two non-disjoint graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, it always seems to be the case that $G_1$ and $G_2$ can be thought of as subgraphs of some bigger graph $G$, and $G_1 \cup G_2$ is another subgraph of $G$. With this assumption, there is no confusion with the incidence function: the incidence functions of $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both restrictions of the incidence function of $G$, and so we can simply remember this incidence function $\phi$ once and for all. If $e \in E(G_1) \cap E(G_2)$, then the endpoints of $e$ in both $G_1$ and $G_2$ are given by $\phi(e)$.

It is very common that the edges $E(G_1)$ and $E(G_2)$ are disjoint anyway: such situations are called *decompositions*. (For example, a multigraph $G$ where all degrees are even has a *cycle decomposition*, where $G$ is written as the union of cycles, and each edge of $G$ is present in exactly one of the cycles.) However, it is not required.

---

When working with simple graphs, there is also no problem. Here, we typically identify an edge with its unordered pair of endpoints, so if an edge is present in both $G_1$ and $G_2$, it *must* have the same endpoints in both. In particular, this means that $G_1 \cup G_2$ is also a simple graph. It is characterized by saying that vertices $x$ and $y$ are adjacent in $G_1 \cup G_2$ exactly when they are adjacent in at least one of $G_1$ or $G_2$; because edges do not have identity, nothing more needs to be said.

I can imagine the rare scenario where we want to take the "edge-disjoint union" of two simple graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$; we artificially distinguish $E(G_1)$ and $E(G_2)$ so that there is no overlap, and then $G_1 \cup G_2$ is a multigraph where two vertices $x,y$ have two parallel edges between then if they were adjacent in both $G_1$ and $G_2$. (A nice feature of the edge-disjoint union is that when $V(G_1) = V(G_2)$, it corresponds to adding adjacency matrices.) However, most of the time, this is **not** what we expect from the union of two simple graphs.